# IO read not reading entire file

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

I have a very large text  file, 958 MBAnd I have created the following script

```
f = IO.read ("Playback.xml").encode ("utf-8", replace: nil)    
separate_files_array = f.scan /strong text<Bla>.*?<\/Bla>/
counter=0
separate_files_array.each do |x|
    .
    .
    .
end
```

The following code only iterates over the first 31 occurences of that regex - and I have no idea why.

No, there is no way these are all the occurrences, I could see its not, and the script runs for a few seconds - this makes no sense for a file that size

Comment: It's impossible to know what's happening without the actual `Playback.xml` file - what's the smallest possible file that will reproduce the error?  Can you find some way to either attach it here, or post it somewhere?

Comment: It's a 900 MB file of text containing a lot of XMLs where Bla is root and between each Bla node there is garbage. The script is meant to break it into smaller files.

Comment: There is no way of copying it -

Comment: Are you sure the culprit is `IO.read` or is it possible that the error is somewhere else? What's the reason for `.encode("utf-8", replace: nil)`? `replace:nil` is the default.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `IO.read` is creating a buffer on default - and loading only part of the file to cache - In the end I used the following to answer my question

[Regexp search through a very large file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910199/regexp-search-through-a-very-large-file)

the reason is because File.read is not creating a buffer on default - which when using a too big a file can cause the program to crush.