# Ruby script which can replace a string in a binary file to a different, but same length string?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, replace, binary

I would like to write a Ruby script (repl.rb) which can replace a string in a binary file (string is defined by a regex) to a different, but same length string.
It works like a filter, outputs to STDOUT, which can be redirected (ruby repl.rb data.bin > data2.bin), regex and replacement can be hardcoded. My approach is:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

fn = ARGV[0]

regex = /\-\-[0-9a-z]{32,32}\-\-/

replacement = "--0ca2765b4fd186d6fc7c0ce385f0e9d9--"

blk_size = 1024

File.open(fn, "rb") {|f|
  while not f.eof?
    data = f.read(blk_size)
    data.gsub!(regex, str)
    print data
  end
}
```

My problem is that when string is positioned in the file that way it interferes with the block size used by reading the binary file. For example when blk_size=1024 and my 1st occurance of the string begins at byte position 1000, so I will not find it in the "data" variable. Same happens with the next read cycle. Should I process the whole file two times with different block size to ensure avoiding this worth case scenario, or is there any other approach?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regexp search through a very large file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910199/regexp-search-through-a-very-large-file)

Answer (score 1):

I would posit that a tool like sed might be a better choice for this. That said, here's an idea: Read block 1 and block 2 and join them into a single string, then perform the replacement on the combined string. Split them apart again and print block 1. Then read block 3 and join block 2 and 3 and perform the replacement as above. Split them again and print block 2. Repeat until the end of the file. I haven't tested it, but it ought to look something like this:

```
File.open(fn, "rb") do |f|
  last_block, this_block = nil

  while not f.eof?
    last_block, this_block = this_block, f.read(blk_size)
    data = "#{last_block}#{this_block}".gsub(regex, str)
    last_block, this_block = data.slice!(0, blk_size), data
    print last_block
  end

  print this_block
end
```

There's probably a nontrivial performance penalty for doing it this way, but it could be acceptable depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a cheeky

```
f.pos = f.pos - replacement.size
```

at the end of the while loop, just before reading the next chunk.